# Orthogonal matrix: 2 norm

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

I would be really thankful if you help me solve this problem. I need to prove that if $P$ and $Q$ are orthogonal matrices, this is true:
$$\mathbf{\|PAQ\|_2=\|A\|_2}$$
I've only got to this :
$$\|\mathbf{PAQ}\|_2=\max\limits_{||x||_2=1}\|\mathbf{PAQ}x\|_2 $$  As $\mathbf{P}$  is an orthogonal matrix,  $$\max\limits_{ \|x||_2=1}\|\mathbf{PAQ}x\|_2=\max\limits_{||x||_2=1}\|\mathbf{AQ}x\|_2$$.
I'm not sure about how to continue. 
Thanks!!!!

Comment: The maximum is certainly not taken on $\mathbb{R}^n$. It is taken on the set of vectors of norm $\leq 1$. Now use the fact that multiplication by an orthogonal matrix sends bijectively the  set of vectors of norm $\leq 1$ to itself (why ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, $x$ ranges over the unit ball and not the whole space.

Observe that $\{Qx:\|x\|\le1\} =\{y:\|y\|\le 1\}$, that is, $Q$ maps the unit ball into itself, bijectively because we're in a finite dimensional space. So, their supremum is the same.